# YouTrack query to retrieve subtasks of Features with given tag

Tags: youtrack

Is there a way in YouTrack to run a query to find all the issues which are Subtasks of any "Feature" issue which contains a given tag?

In other words, find all issues with Type: Feature and tag: Foo, then return any issues that are Subtasks of the result.

I'm currently using YouTrack 5.2.5 but happy to upgrade if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible to perform such search in YouTrack.
You can only search for `Type:Feature tag: Foo` and then find subtasks of each found feature with a script or manually.